# Gmail Apps Script question - customizing pre-written script

Tags: google-apps-script, merge, gmail

I am using https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/mail-merge to use data in a google sheet for a gmail merge project.  There is a script that is run, that works perfectly for my purposes.  But then there is additional code provided for some customizations - I would like the recipients to see my name, versus my email address, as the sender.  What do I do with this additional code to customize the script as I'd like?  Meaning where in the larger script code do I paste it, and how do I modify it for what I want?

Illogically, but maybe understandably, I've tried nothing.  I'm not "paralyzed with fear," but I'm looking for a clean answer that will help me, versus me flailing away trying to make it work.  Yes, I've searched google and this forum.

Comment: The assumption is that you are programmer trying to learn google apps script.  In my experience some flailing is required.

Comment: If you are using [a sample script creted by Martin](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/mail-merge#code-source), how about modifying `// name: 'name of the sender',` to `name: 'your name',`? But, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result because of my poor English skill. So, I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution to your issue. I apologize for this.

Comment: Related question: [Modifying a google appscript to attach files from column in sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76563094/1330560)

Comment: @Tanaike thank you.  Your response fixed it for me.

Comment: @7983grover Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your reply, when your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answser? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer to question, courtesy of @Tanaike:

> modifying // name: 'name of the sender', to name: 'your name'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).